# How to vertical align element relative other element with pseudo-class?

Tags: css

I have multiple boxes (items) with an item number and a description. I want to vertical align my item number regardless of the description height (using only HTML and CSS).

See this image for more info:
[image]

```
<div class="item">
    <div class="item-number">1</div>
    <div class="item-description">Text placeholder</div>
</div>
```

As you can see I have multiple boxes and the description text can have different lengths, so I can't absolute position my item number relative to the top.

Any one got any suggestions on how to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should position your number absolutely in order to achieve this. You could also minimalize markup by using a pseudo element, allowing you to do this with a single element.

I have also used a `data-attr` in order to allow you to dynamically alter the number within the div if you so wish.

Something like:

```css
div {
  width: 200px;
  border: 5px solid lightgray;
  box-shadow: 5px 5px 10px dimgray;
  margin: 20px;
  padding: 20px;
  padding-left: 30px;
  position: relative;
}
div:before {
  content: attr(data-pointNum);
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: -5px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  height: 40px;
  width: 40px;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 30px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 5px solid tomato;
  background: white;
  box-shadow: 5px 5px 10px dimgray;
}
```

```html
<div data-pointNum="1">some text</div>
<div data-pointNum="2">some moretext
  <br/>spanning multiple
  <br/>lines</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/UI_Designer/xzmzpL4g/1/

```
.item{
    border:1px solid #000;  
    padding:20px;
    margin-left:20px;
    position:relative;
    margin-bottom:20px;

}
.item-number{
     position: absolute;
    left:-10px;
    width:20px;
    height:20px;
    border:1px solid #ccc;
    border-radius:50%;
    text-align:center;   
    background:#FFF;
    top: 40%;
  transform: translate(-20%,0);


}
```

Comment: This one does not align properly if the description is only one line.

Answer (score -2):

you can try this

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.item-number').css('top', ($('.item').height() / 2) + 'px');
});
```

```css
.item-description {} .item {
  border: 1px solid #000;
  width: 150px;
  padding-left: 20px;
}
.item-number {
  position: absolute;
  left: 5px;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 50%;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="item">
  <div class="item-number">1</div>
  <div class="item-description">Text placeholder Text placeholder Text placeholder Text placeholder</div>
</div>
```

and this is demo
https://jsfiddle.net/0xf5hvej/
of course you will need more styling to achieve what you need but this is the basic

Comment: for this functionality, jQuery is overkill.

Comment: Do not post a JavaScript solution for a CSS question unless you are absolutely 100% positive there is not a pure CSS solution.